# Get Around the "Initialization of immutable value 'variableName' was never used" Warning in Swift 3 Switch Statements

Tags: swift, switch-statement

So I have some code that looks like this:

```
fileprivate func enumSwitchTime(_ optionalString: String?) {
    if let nextEnumToSwitchOn = funcToGetEnum()
    switch nextEnumToSwitchOn {
    case .enumStateOne(let associatedEnumValue):
        if let optionalString = optionalString {
            //do stuff with both associatedEnumValue and optionalString
        }
    case .enumStateTwo...
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

However since Swift 3 (I'm using Xcode 8.1) I am getting the "Initialization of immutable value 'associatedEnumValue' was never used..." warning on the that first case.

I am still getting my toes wet in Swift, but so far I see no way around this. I can't do an underscore parameter in the case statement and then declare the associated enum value later, after the let optionalString = optionalString, or at least I haven't found any way of doing that.

It is just a warning, but I don't like warnings in my code. Any way around this?

Comment: Why do you get a "'associatedEnumValue' was never used" warning if you "do stuff with associatedEnumValue"? – Can you post a compiling self-contained example?

Comment: If you don't need the associated value then just match on `case .enumStateOne:`. Otherwise you should not get a warning (unless I am overlooking something).

Comment: `if let nextEnumToSwitchOn = funcToGetEnum()` without a matching block to follow wont even compile. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and thereafter consider updating your question. In the progress of writing such a MCVE, I suspect you might even answer your own question (which is another good reason to create minimal, _complete_ and verifiable examples).

Comment: Martin R,

I do need the associated value, but I only use it after confirming that the optionalString parameter is not nil. So yes, the warning is correct: there is a code path whereby associatedEnumValue is not used. I am merely wondering if there is a tip that people have for getting around this.

I will see if I can get some code that compiles up later today.

Comment: There shouldn't be a warning if the variable is used in *any* code path.

Comment: Yep, it was Xcode. I only posted here after I could not get the warning to go away, but of course as soon as I did, the warning went away. I did, however, learn about MCVE for the next time I post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out this was an Xcode error/issue.

After cleaning my project and restarting Xcode multiple times, and the warning persisting, I posted the question here thinking I was missing something.

After Martin R said if the variable is used in any code path the warning shouldn't be there, I futzed around with the code, undid those changes, cleaned the project, restarted Xcode and FINALLY the warning went away.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this warning